# How to make a loop or a shorter code in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-1.4

I have the following code

```
$cp = new Criteria();
$cp->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::BIZORG_ID, $bizorg->getBizorgId());  
$cp->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::TYPE_ID, 1);                           
$cp_count = ProductBrandServicePeer::doCount($cp);
$cs = new Criteria();
$cs->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::BIZORG_ID, $bizorg->getBizorgId());  
$cs->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::TYPE_ID, 3);
$cs_count = ProductBrandServicePeer::doCount($cs);
$cb = new Criteria();
$cb->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::BIZORG_ID, $bizorg->getBizorgId());  
$cb->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::TYPE_ID, 2);                      
$cb_count = ProductBrandServicePeer::doCount($cb);
```

I would like to make it shorter or to make a loop.
I am thinking something like this:

```
$cb->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::TYPE_ID, array(1,2,3);
```

But then how do I get the cp_count, cs_count and cb_count variables?

Comment: Depends on whether you use the variable $cp, $cs, $cb later in the code. You can easilly use a  for(each) loop to reduce it but you'll need more changes if you need to access them later.

Comment: and the down vote is for... ?!
What is wrong with StackOverflow in the latest? Last time I got voted down and the voter told me I should go search on Google. Now, again... 
I don't give a dime on votes, I come here for solutions and I offer solutions myself, but this vote system must stop, it shows just intolerance and hatred. Not everyone of us is smart and I might be the last of you but in my opinion this website is about HELP, not votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array(); // to store the counts
for($i = 1; i <= 3; $i++) {
        $c = new Criteria();
        $c->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::BIZORG_ID, $bizorg->getBizorgId());  
        $c->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::TYPE_ID, $i);                           
        $array[$i - 1] = ProductBrandServicePeer::doCount($c); // let's store the count in the array
    }
```

output :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  **cpcount**
  [1]=>
  **cscount**
  [2]=>
  **cbcount**
}
```

Comment: This is awesome!
Did I say Thank You!

Comment: careful, I did a mistake in the condition of the loop. fixed.

Answer (score 2):

To use the same variables later in the code, use variable variables. :D

```
    foreach (['cp' => 1, 'cs' => 3, 'cb' => 2] as $var => $typeId) {
        $$var->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::BIZORG_ID, $bizorg->getBizorgId());
        $$var->add(ProductBrandServicePeer::TYPE_ID, $typeId);
        ${$var.'_count'} = ProductBrandServicePeer::doCount($$var);
    }
```

Comment: smart! I like this, too, even if I don't need to use it later, I believe this is a clever solution.